# slide out menu R.id.home error in android 2.2

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am new to android , 
I am currently working on the FB style slide out menu. I find out many sample project here but could not be able to run that successfully in android 2.2(froyo) version as they are working fine in android 3.x version like **HONEYCOMB** .

the error occur at ::`if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)`

here, home is not recognized
and also at::
`getActionBar()` marking that this method is not defined:
and in values file under res "values-v11" is giving error

thanks in advance for GOOD replies

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you're using APIs that were only added in Honeycomb, and hence cannot be use in older versions of Android.

These APIs are likely to be the ActionBar and maybe Fragments.

To use these features in older versions, you can use the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) by Jake Wharton and the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) from Google. These collectively allow you to use ActionBars, Fragments etc on older versions of Android.

Comment: Android Support library 10 is already installed.but how to deal with ActionBarSherlock ??

Comment: Just download and add the Jar to your project's `/libs` folder.

Comment: i think going to the right direction but my problem not solved yet> i also include the jar file to libs in my project.values-v11 is now error free but he other two are still giving the same error:

Comment: You will need to modify your code to use the support libraries and the ABS. Go through the tutorials online for both of them. There are tons of them.

Comment: OK . can you figure out the simple way to implement the Slide out menu .??